# angular js related to controller and custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[i should get output like that in second div i should get inplace of headers i should get income which is mentioned in the controller object data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGXcj.png)

I just need **different content in two div** when I changed the data in controller object it should be reflected in div. 
here is my html code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    ***emphasized text***
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-gridster.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wid.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body   ng-controller="myController" >
      <div gridster  ng-controller="myCtrl"  > 
        <ul>
          <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items">
            <div my-widget ></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

my `script` goes here which contains the `controller` as well as `directive`.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['gridster'])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){

    $scope.Items = [
      { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0, },
      { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0, }
    ]   

});


app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.content=[{
    data:54565463,
    right:67566,
    title:'headers'},
    { data:65476756,
      right:123,
      title:"Income",
 }]

});


 app.directive('myWidget',function(){

        return{ 
            restrict:"EA",
            scope:{ 
             title:'@',
             data:'=',
             },
            templateUrl:'spare.html',
            }
        });
```

and my `spare html` is below -

```
<span ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="panel-body "   ng-style = "myStyle">
    <h1  class="title" >{{content.title}}</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-dollar" ></i>{{content.data}}</div>
     <p id="rightcorner" ><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i>{{content.right}} 
     </p>
    </span>
```

what i need is  in 2 div's i should get separate data which is give`enter code here`n in controller object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive is using an isolated scope (`scope:{ title:'@', data:'='}`). That's why it doesn't have access to the `content` array of the parent scope (which is a good thing in general).

What you wanna do is to pass an item of `$scope.content` to the `my-widget` directive.

You could use the `$index` variable of the `ngRepeat` scope.

```
<li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items">
    <div my-widget data="content[$index]"></div>
</li>
```

As the `my-widget` directive has its own scope, you have to change the binding expressions (there is no thing called `content` in the directive scope).

```
<div class="panel-body">
<h1  class="title" >{{title}}</h1>
<i class="fa fa-dollar" ></i>{{data.data}}
</div>
 <p id="rightcorner"><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i>{{data.right}} 
 </p>
```

By the way, `title` is a bad name for an attribute, as it's an html attribute.

**EDIT**: Added example code for a solution with a single controller, as asked in comments.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myController', myController)
  .directive('myWidget', myWidget);
  
function myController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.items = [
  {
    title: "1",
    obj: { data: 123 }
  },
  {
    title: "2",
    obj: { data: 234 }
  }];
}

function myWidget() {
  return {
    scope: {
      data: '<'
    },
    template: '<div>Widget: {{data.data}}</div>'
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController as $ctrl" >
  <div> 
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
        <div ng-bind="item.title"></div>
        <div my-widget data="item.obj"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i remove "myctrl" and add that object in "mycontroller" it means i just need to use only   1 controller  is that possible @hansmaad

Comment: yes of course, just put `content` into `mycontroller` and remove the `myctrl` if this better suits your needs

Comment: i had tried but it is not working for me can u help me out with this like  $scope.Items = [
  { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj :{  data:54565463,
right:67566,
title:'headers'}  },
  { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0, obj :{data:65476756,
right:123,
title:"Income",} }
  ]   still it is not working for me

Comment: @Bunty I added an example. I'm sure you're able to figure out, how to translate this for your needs.

Comment: now what i need is want to see font size different in each div and it should be passed in object only is that possible @hansmaad

Comment: @pradeep Of course, have a look at ngStyle and ngClass

Comment: @pradeep You can bind the font-size from `item.obj.fontSize` to `ng-style` for example. Just try it, and ask a new question if you've problems. That's not scope of this question.